# Converting a string to a bytes object as is

Tags: python, python-3.x

How do I turn a string into a bytes object *as is*, i.e. without encoding it? I can't use `.encode()` here, because it's corrupting my binary file after saving.

```
filedata = pathlib.Path('file.bin').read_bytes()
# since i can't modify a bytes object, i should convert it to a string, should I?
data = ''
for i in filedata:
    data += chr(i) if isinstance(i, int) else i
data[3] = '\x01'
data += '\x58\x02\x0C\x80\x61\x39\x56\x18\x55\x61\x89\x42\x42\x16\x46\x17\x54\x70\x10\x58\x60\x10\x10\x01\x75\x10\xF0\xC0\x00\x01\x00\x02\x00\xC0\x00\xD0\x00\x01\x00\xC4\x00\x01\x00\x02\x00\x01\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00'
pathlib.Path('result.bin').write_bytes(data.encode()) # doesn't work as it should
```

So instead of this:

```
58 02 0C 80 61 39 56 18 55 61 89 42 42 16 46 17 54 70 10 58 60 10 10 01 75 10 F0 C0 00 01 00 02 00 C0 00 D0 00 01 00 C4 00 01 00 02 00 01 00 00 02 00 00 00
```

I get this:

```
58 02 0C C2 80 61 39 56 18 55 61 C2 89 42 42 16 46 17 54 70 10 58 60 10 10 01 75 10 C3 B0 C3 80 00 01 00 02 00 C3 80 00 C3 90 00 01 00 C3 84 00 01 00 02 00 01 00 00 02 00 00 00
```

I tried modifying a bytes object itself, but I'm always getting that error:

> TypeError: 'bytes' object does not support item assignment

Comment: use `pickle` library

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? `filedata = filedata.replace(filedata[3], b'\x01', 1)` might be all you need.

Comment: @chepner doesn't work: `TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'int'`

Comment: Oops. Replace the first argument with `bytes(filedata[3:4])` instead.

Comment: `filedata.[3].to_bytes(1, 'big')` might be more efficient, though. (The second argument doesn't really matter since the first argument is 1.)

Comment: @chepner thanks, replacing works, but how do i insert new items? `.append`, `.insert` and the `+` operator don't work.

Comment: You don't; you combine existing `bytes` values to create new ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I turn a string into a bytes object AS IS, i.e. without encoding it?

You can't. That's a contradiction of terms — as of Python 3.

A *string* is a sequence of text characters. Think letters, punctuation, white-space, even control characters. A *bytes* object is a sequence of 8-bit numbers. How the two sequences are related is a question of encoding. There is no way around it.

Text characters should be thought of as abstract entities. The letter A, for example, simply exists. There is no number associated with it *per se*. (Internally, it is represented by a Unicode code point, which *is* a number, but that's an implementation detail.)

In the code above, you're reading bytes and you're writing bytes, and in between you want to manipulate the byte stream: change one of the numbers, append others.

Python `bytes` are no different from `str` in that regard: they are both immutable types. If you did the same as above but with a string, you'd get the same kind of error:

```
>>> s = 'abcd'
>>> s[3] = 'x'
TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment
```

That is, in-place character manipulation is not supported for strings. There are other ways to achieve the same result though. In-place byte manipulation, on the other hand, *is* supported — arguably because it's a use case that is more common than for strings. You just need to use [`bytearray`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytearray) instead of `bytes`:

```
>>> data = bytearray(b'\x00\x01\x02\x03\x04')
>>> data[3] = 255
>>> print(data)
bytearray(b'\x00\x01\x02\xff\x04')
```

Which you can then write to a file without any encoding whatsoever:

```
pathlib.Path('result.bin').write_bytes(data)
```

(Note that `bytes` literals must be prefixed with `b`.)

Answer (score 0):

Solved (thanks to John):

```
filedata = bytearray(pathlib.Path(sys.argv[1]).read_bytes())
# filedata = bytearray(open(sys.argv[1], 'rb').read()) also works
filedata[1] = 255 # modifying a single byte (0 - 255)
filedata[0:1] = b'\xff' # inserting bytes
filedata.extend(255) # appending one single byte
filedata.extend(filedata2) # appending another array of bytes (bytearray object)
filedata.extend(b'\xff\xff') # appending bytes
filedata.extend([255, 255]) # appending bytes too
pathlib.Path(sys.argv[1]).write_bytes(filedata) # write data to a file
# open(sys.argv[1], 'rb').write(filedata) should work too
```

---

<sub>This was originally added to [revision 5](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/56878574/5) of the question.</sub>